Out of bounds error when using stratified k fold during deep train/validation loop
With the following code:
def __init__(self, model, num_folds=5, batch_size=32, epochs=10, lr=0.001, betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-8):
    """
    Initialize the ModelTrainer with specified parameters.

    Args:
        model (torch.nn.Module): The PyTorch model to be trained and validated.
        num_folds (int): The number of folds for stratified k-fold cross-validation. Default is 5.
        batch_size (int): Batch size for training and validation. Default is 32.
        epochs (int): Number of epochs for training. Default is 10.
        lr (float): Learning rate for the optimizer. Default is 0.001.
        betas (tuple): Coefficients used for computing running averages of gradient and its square.
                       Default is (0.9, 0.999).
        eps (float): Term added to the denominator to improve numerical stability in the optimizer.
                     Default is 1e-8.
    """
    self.model = model
    self.num_folds = num_folds
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.epochs = epochs
    self.lr = lr
    self.betas = betas
    self.eps = eps

def train_and_validate(self, data, labels):
    """
    Train and validate the model using stratified k-fold cross-validation.

    Args:
        data (torch.Tensor): The input data for training and validation.
        labels (torch.Tensor): The labels corresponding to the input data.

    Returns:
        auc_scores (list): A list of AUC scores for each fold.
        sensitivities (list): Sensitivities at 100% specificity for each fold.
        mean_auc (float): Mean AUC score across all folds.
        mean_sensitivity (float): Mean sensitivity at 100% specificity across all folds.
    """
    # Initialize StratifiedKFold
    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=self.num_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

    # Lists to store AUC scores and sensitivities for each fold
    auc_scores = []
    sensitivities = []

    # Lists to store ROC curve data for each fold
    tprs = []
    mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

    # Iterate over folds
    for fold, (train_index, val_index) in enumerate(skf.split(data, labels)):
        # Get the data for this fold
        X_train_fold, X_val_fold = data[train_index], data[val_index]
        y_train_fold, y_val_fold = labels[train_index], labels[val_index]

        # Create PyTorch datasets and data loaders for this fold
        train_dataset = TensorDataset(X_train_fold, y_train_fold)
        val_dataset = TensorDataset(X_val_fold, y_val_fold)
        train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=self.batch_size, shuffle=True)
        val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=self.batch_size)

        # Define loss function and optimizer
        criterion = nn.BCELoss()
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=self.lr, betas=self.betas, eps=self.eps)

        # Training loop for this fold
        for epoch in range(self.epochs):
            self.model.train()
            for inputs, labels in train_loader:
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                outputs = self.model(inputs)
                loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()

        # Validation loop for this fold
        self.model.eval()
        val_outputs_list = []
        val_labels_list = []
        for inputs, labels in val_loader:
            with torch.no_grad():
                val_outputs = self.model(inputs)
                val_outputs_list.append(val_outputs.numpy())
                val_labels_list.append(labels.numpy())
        val_outputs_np = np.concatenate(val_outputs_list)
        val_labels_np = np.concatenate(val_labels_list)

        # Calculate ROC curve for this fold
        fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(val_labels_np, val_outputs_np)
        roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
        auc_scores.append(roc_auc)

        # Calculate sensitivity at 100% specificity
        sensitivity = np.interp(1e-3, fpr, tpr)
        sensitivities.append(sensitivity)

        # Store ROC curve data for this fold
        tprs.append(np.interp(mean_fpr, fpr, tpr))
        tprs[-1][0] = 0.0

        # Plot ROC curve for this fold
        plt.plot(fpr, tpr, lw=1, alpha=0.3)

    # Plot settings
    plt.xlim([-0.05, 1.05])
    plt.ylim([-0.05, 1.05])
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) Curve')
    plt.show()

    # Calculate mean ROC curve
    mean_tpr = np.mean(tprs, axis=0)
    mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)

    # Plot mean ROC curve with thicker line
    plt.plot(mean_fpr, mean_tpr, color='black', lw=2, linestyle='--', label=f'Mean ROC (AUC = {mean_auc:.2f})')
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    plt.show()

    # Calculate mean sensitivity at 100% specificity
    mean_sensitivity = np.mean(sensitivities)

    return auc_scores, sensitivities, mean_auc, mean_sensitivity

I constantly get the index out of bounds error in y_train_fold, y_val_fold = labels[train_index], labels[val_index] when the second fold wants to begin. The first fold runs. My data is shaped
(864,19,500) and my binary labels (864). Can anyone spot something wrong with this code that might trigger the error?
I tried balancing the class distributions with SMOTE, checking the length and shapes of the labels but I could not get it working. During the first fold, the length of labels is 864, but during the second fold, the shape becomes 24 when I use num_folds=4, resulting in the out of bounds error at index 24 for dimension 0 with size 24

If labels is a pandas.Series object then labels[train_index] will be using the dataframe's original indices rather than the linear numpy indices. The two won't necessarily be aligned.
Either ensure labels is converted to a numpy array, or alternatively keep it as a Series but index into it using labels.iloc[train_index].

The labels supplied to def train_and_validate(self, data, labels) are getting overwritten with the subsequent lines for inputs, labels in train_loader: and for inputs, labels in val_loader:.
Try renaming the latter two to labels_train and labels_val.

Thanks for your answer Muhammed! My inputs are numpy arrays, that's why I am so confused.

No problem. I've updated my answer with another suggestion.
